# Create files inside a directory with the directory's name

Tags: files, directory

I'm using the following command to create a `.m3u` playlist in a directory with music:

```
 ls -1v | grep .opus > Playlist.m3u
```

How can I automatically name the m3u-file after the folder?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way without ls and grep, just the builtin printf

```
printf '%s\n' *.opus > "${PWD##*/}.m3u"
```

or abusing set

```
set -- *.opus "$@"
printf '%s\n' "$@" > "${PWD##*/}.m3u"
```

The latter creates an array. btw both solution does not use any external commands all of them are builtin from the shell

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the command you have supplied

```
 ls -1v | grep .opus > "${PWD##*/}".m3u
```

will create a file with the name of the current directory and `.m3u` extension.